# Forced sharding in mongodb, tag aware sharding?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm interested in building a system to query log files produced on a fairly large number of independent machines.

Rather than have them all sent to one central database, I'd like to treat the whole of the machines as one distributed database.

Right now I'm looking at Mongo to do that. Each machine's logs would be one shard stored on that machine.

Data loss would be fine and redundancy is not required at all. It is very important that each machine be accountable for one shard and only contain the logs it produced.

Reading through the docs, it seems that the much more common use case is to support redundancy and automatic balancing. It does look like tag aware sharding could do what I want: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/tag-aware-sharding/.

Since I'm newer to Mongo, I thought I'd reach out for some experienced opinion before doing a deep dive. Is what I want to do here possible without bending the tool? Are there any big pros/cons of this use case I should know about before proceeding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting answers to the following questions should help you design your system.

- How many logging hosts are you talking about?
- Are those hosts distributed on different geographical sites?
- How many log entries to store per unit of time? (for example, 1M per day?)
- How long do you want to keep the log entries?
- Do you care if you lose your data?
- Do you want to have a failover to another system if the host with your DB fails?

As for my understanding, why do you state: "It is very important that each machine be accountable for one shard and only contain the logs it produced"?

Another important thing to keep in mind is that NoSQL solutions are usually dependent on how you want to use your data. Planning for the queries you want to perform on your data will influence your design and the schema for your data.

Would the preferred setting be using only one host to keep all the logs?
I would not recommend having one shard per host that is logging info. In that setting, queries would be slow if you have a lot of hosts. Instead log to the file system and push those logs to MongoDB, or use a logging application like Splunk.

If you care about loosing all your data, use more replica set members (secondaries).

If you want to do any backup or failover, other hosts (secondaries) are recommended.

If you decide to go with sharding, and each shard has a different "tag", then no balancing should occur between the shards. Balancing occur when MongoDB detects that one shard is becoming larger than another. It then moves documents from the large shard to a smaller one. If you force documents to live on a specific shard with "tags", then they can't move.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Daniel. To answer your questions for the sake of curiosity, the system has a top end use-case of tens of thousands of machines and data privacy reasons prevent cross-shard sharing of logs. I should have enough info to go from here!